# when importing functions from inside builtins like os or sys is it good practice to import as protected?

Tags: python

in `myModule.py` I am importing `environ` from `os` , like

`from os import environ` since I am only using environ, but when I do `dir(myModule)` it shows `environ` as publicly visible , how ever should it be imported as protected assuming some other project may also have its own `environ` function ?

Comment: I think you might be confused.  `myModule.environ` won't conflict with `yourModule.environ` -- They're in different namespaces...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing `from os import environ`, then you'll reference it as `environ`.

If you do `import os`, it's `os.environ`.

So depending on your needs, the second option might be better.  The first will look better and read easier, whereas the second avoids namespace pollution.

Comment: can you do `import os.environ` ?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @mgilson's comment - when you do `dir(somemodule)`, everything you see is namespaced to that module. In other words, you have to use the `.` (name resolution operator) to "reach" those items.

So, in `myModule.py` you have the following lines:

```
from os import environ

a = 4
```

In some other module, or the Python prompt, you have the following statements:

```
import myModule
dir(myModule)
```

Now, in order to get to `a` or `environ` that is inside `myModule`, you'd have to explicitly define its scope:

```
print(a) # this won't work
print(myModule.a) # this will print 4
```

In Python as a general rule, there is no explicit hiding/protecting.  Python expects its users to be consenting adults and "know what they are doing".

However, developers can control what happens when someone tries to import everything from a module (`from myModule import *`), but this isn't strictly enforced. You can still get to everything inside myModule by prefixing the module name.